# TensorFlow: Labels as relations between examples

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a somewhat unusual learning task: the "labels" for my examples (i.e., images) are actually relations between specific images. For instance, suppose each batch consists of `2*n` images, where the pair `(i, j)` has label `1` while the pair `(j, i)` has label `-1`. Suppose most (i.e., the *vast* majority) pairs possible from the set of images lack any label, and as such random sampling will only rarely yield even a single relation to train on. Therefore, in this example, each batch consists of a set `2N` images, `N` pairs of which are known to have some relation.

TensorFlow is so flexible it's easy to design a net that can compute the appropriate loss function. However, creating the input is problematic. I don't remember C++ well enough to implement a custom input op, so I either have to read the data into python in the appropriate manner and feed it to TensorFlow (easy, but slow) or glue some ops together to get it to work if possible.

Accomplishing this appears very unwieldy, requiring many queue objects (why do readers only accept queues in TensorFlow?!). Assuming that I have some set of files which are serialized examples, each a list of the form `{file1: <...>, file2: <...>, label: <...>}`, is there a simple way to serve them to the net as a tensor of shape `2N * W * H * C` (with image i and image i + 1 belonging to a single relation, where i is `(0, 2, 4, 6, ...)` i.e., `[relation_n_image_1, relation_n_image_2, relation_m_image_1, ...]`)? My current creation, individual components of which work but works as a whole only in theory, employs 5 queue objects of various kinds and does not shuffle perfectly.

Comment: Why not have a ```RandomShuffleQueue``` that enqueues (with a loading thread) elements of shape 2, W, H, C (pairs of images)? Shuffeling happens then on this level, and after dequeuing you can move from N, 2, W, H, C to 2N, W, H, C.

Comment: I could, although there are many

Comment: Sorry hit respond too fast. I could indeed do that, but the queues seem pretty i flexible. And since theres about ten thousand more pairs than images themselves, which means that id have to store terabytes of image pairs